# Spring Boot HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this class to represent a User:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles;

    public UserDto() {
    }
}
```

}

What I'm trying to do is to let Spring map @RequestBody of the controller below to a UserDto:

```
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) throws Exception {
        UserDto existingUserDto;

        try {
            existingUserDto = userService.save(userDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(existingUserDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

But instead what when I try to send a Post request I get the following error from Spring:

```
Failed to read HTTP message:                 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2c477da6; line: 1, column: 10]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2c477da6; line: 1, column: 10]
```

What I tried to do was declaring a custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter but I didn't get any different result

```
@Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }
```

Here a screen of the requested I'm doing ( with Content-Type: application/json):

[PostMan Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqwVw.png)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Show us the JSON content in the request body.

Comment: You're sending form data, not JSON. Get rid of the `@RequestBody`. This should be a simple form parameter.

Comment: Added a screen of the request, thank for your reply.

Comment: What if I what to keep the @RequestBody ? What should I change?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank for your reply but if i get rid of  `@RequestBody` then the controller receive the object UserDto with all this fields mapped to null.

Comment: You are sending form data not JSON formatted bean. RequestBody annotation expects a json of user bean, You may try ModelAttribute annotation if you want to send as form data or manually get each of the parameter with RequestParam annotation and initialize your UserDto.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please change your controller method `@RequestMapping` to the following.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
```

Also you don't need to add a a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to get this thing done.Also make sure you have correct request mapping annotated in your controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
```

Also remove the following annotations in your model class. Add getters and setters to all the properties while keeping the default constructor.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
```

Hope this helps. happy coding !

Comment: Thank for your reply! Unfortunately changing the `@RequestMapping` didn't work and I'm still getting the same error as before. I've also double checked the `@RequestMapping` and it's correct since I've declared `server.contextPath=/api` in my application.proprieties file. Thank you again :)

Comment: Answer was updated. Try that out. What is the JSON you are posting here?

Comment: I've tried to also to remove all the annotation but nothing is changing. `@Getters` and `@Setter` is a feature of [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) that give you setter and getter by annotation. I didn't understand what JSON you are referring to with your last question.

Comment: your JSON payload which was posted to the API

Comment: Okay I solved the problem! As you were probably thinking the problem was how i was sending the request ... my bad. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: If the comment was helpful consider flagging it as useful :)