# POST , PATCH , PUT calls with body not working through Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a backend service with GET and POST calls which work fine with direct end-points but when I call them through spring cloud gateway - the GET calls works fine but POST/PATCH/PUT calls return 504 gateway error. Further analyzing the logs , it is exactly the below errors that is thrown. **The back-end service gets called when I remove the body for these POST/PATCH/PUT calls but with body is throwing the below error** - I also have given the config snapshot below. Please can you advice what is wrong with this?

message: Http Error Code: 500.  org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:310)

Http Error Code: 400. Validation failed: org.springframework.http.converter.**HttpMessageNotReadableExceptio**n: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is org.apache.catalina.connector.**ClientAbortException:** java.io.EOFException

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: backend-service
          uri: http://backend-service:8080/
          predicates:
            - Path=/backend-service/**
            - Method=GET,POST,PATCH
```

**Here is my controller :**

```
@PostMapping("/id/{Id}") 
public ResponseEntity<Void> modifyTableData(@PathVariable String Id,@RequestBody UpdateRequest updateRequest) {
 
    repository.updateId(Id, updateRequest.getId(), updateRequest.getCountry()); 
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build(); 
}
```

**Here is the request body :**

```
{
"Id": 12345,
"country": "IN",
"email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
"name":"Ravi"
}
```

Request DTO :

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UpdateRequest {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private Long Id;
    @JsonProperty("country")
    private String country;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

Not to mention again , the same request with DELETE method works fine - it is a problem only with PATCH/PUT/POST.

Comment: `The back-end service gets called when I remove the body for these POST/PATCH/PUT calls but with body is throwing the below error` - are you sure the problem isn't inside of the controller? could you share how one of the calls is implemented and which model is used?

Comment: @thinkgruen : The problem is definitely not inside the controller - because when I send the request with body - the call does not even enter the controller , it fails before reaching the controller. It only enters If I don't send the body and the same happens with all the end-points that's PUT/PATCH/POST. I suspect it is a problem with Spring cloud gateway config.

Comment: Here's my call , 
@PostMapping("/id/{Id}")
 public ResponseEntity<Void> modifyTableData(@PathVariable String Id,@RequestBody UpdateRequest updateRequest) {
        repository.updateId(Id, updateRequest.getId(), updateRequest .getCode());
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

Comment: Knowing the controller is still valuable information. It seems that Spring cannot deserialize the UpdateRequest before delegating it to the modifyTableData method. Could you add the snippet of the controller as well as (parts of) the UpdateRequest to the question itself? There is no formatting inside the comment section. Also helpful would be your request body.

Comment: Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970869/spring-boot-httpmessagenotreadableexception) for what information inside the question is helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated all the details now. Not to mention , it happens only for POST/PUT/PATCH - the same kind of request works fine with DELETE.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful to see the whole picture. For now I have found maybe two hints. You could try routing the requests on `/backend-service/**` to httpbin as suggested in [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2019/06/18/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-gateway) as well as look at your routing in the actuator, e.g. [http://localhost/actuator/gateway/routes/baeldung_route](http://localhost/actuator/gateway/routes/baeldung_route) - see [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway#2-code-implementation)

Comment: Thank you , I did more debug and basically found that the request is reaching the back-end service but the body is missing in all the POST/PUT/PATCH calls. But with DELETE I am able to send the body. Is there a specific configuration needs to be done for POST/PUT & PATCH in spring cloud gateway?